# Using arquillian on domain mode JBoss AS 7.1.3

Tags: jboss, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to setup arquillian to deploy to domain mode Jboss 7.1.3 but I'm experiencing this issue: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1175268.

I can't move to a newer version (ie. Wildfly 8.0.0) that contains this fix at this time. Does anyone know what workaround Martin Simka is referring to in the bugzilla comments when he says:

> This fix simplifies some domain mode tests, it allows us to remove workaround where we have to add server-config to host that is started with host-master.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow thinks to the [JIRA issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2518) then to the [Github Pull Request](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/pull/5477) then to the [commit](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/pull/5477/files) you'll find the proposed fix. It looks like you'll have to recompile AS 7 though to get it applied though.